# output is not in proper manner for 2d array in c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, scanf

two dimentional array in  c
im getting small error which screwing me up..
can u spot any error, while i should get op as

> ```
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6 
> 7 8 9
> ```

but am getting op as

> ```
> 1 2 4
> 4 5 7
> 7 8 9
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int m;
    scanf("%d",&m);
    int a[m][m],i,j;
    for(i=0;i<=m;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=m;j++){
            scanf("%d",&(a[i][j]));
            printf("%d",a[i][j]);

        }

    }

    for(i=0;i<=m;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=m;j++){
            printf("%d",a[i][j]);
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: `<= m` -> `< m`

Comment: Voting to close this as simple typo. We already have countless other questions with off-by-one array access bugs on SO.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration :

```
int a[m][m];
```

means that you have an array with `m` rows and `m` columns, ***numbered from `0` to `m-1`***. You are trying to access elements which do not belong to your array, due to your `<=m` conditions.

Change both of your loops from :

```
for(i=0;i<=m;i++){
    for(j=0;j<=m;j++){
        scanf("%d",&(a[i][j]));
        printf("%d",a[i][j]);
    }
}
```

which you have now, to :

```
for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
        scanf("%d",&(a[i][j]));
        printf("%d",a[i][j]);
    }
}
```

You can read more about indexing and arrays [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Your loops are going beyond the end of your array. An array like `int a[m]` has elements going from 0 to m-1 so your loops should be like this:

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
```